# Normal distribution from a normally distributed variable

Tags: normal-distribution

$X \sim N (1,4) ;\, Y= 2X+1;$

And now does $Y$ have $N(1\times2+1,\, 2\times4+1) = N(3,9)$ ?

Is it valid? And if so why ? Or how do I get y's distribution?

Because when I run
    the following in R, it yields

```
x = dnorm(1,1,4) # [1] 0.09973557

y = dnorm(3,3,9) # [1] 0.04432692
```

Comment: $Var(a \cdot X + b) = a^2 \cdot Var(x)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that $Var(aX+b) = a^2Var(X)$. So your distribution for $Y$ is almost correct, apart from the variance.

Answer (score 0):

The linear transformation of variables is shown [here](http://stattrek.com/random-variable/transformation.aspx).

Suppose a linear transformation is applied to the random variable $X$ to create a new random variable $Y$. Then, the mean and variance of the new random variable $Y$ are defined by the following equations.

$$\bar{Y} = m\bar{X} + b       \text{ and }      Var(Y) = m^2  Var(X)$$

where $m$ and $b$ are constants, $\bar{Y}$ is the mean of $Y$, $\bar{X}$ is the mean of $X$, $Var(Y)$ is the variance of $Y$, and $Var(X)$ is the variance of $X$.

Comment: @atp: If an answer is helpful, please upvote and/or accept the answer.

Comment: @StatMan (+1) For your answer, I don't think OP understood.